# Setting CURL option via Service Container for Guzzle

Tags: symfony, curl, guzzle

I need to set `CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY` CURL option, but the problem is that I don't know how to do it using Service Container of Sf2.

Here is how `Guzzle` is injected now:

```
services:
    user.user_manager:
        class: Foo\UserBundle\Model\UserManager
        arguments:
            - @guzzle.client
```

But I need to add `CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY` as well.

Plain PHP example:

```
$guzzle = new \Guzzle\Http\Client(null, array(
    'curl.options' => array(
        'CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY' => 1
)));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom Guzzle client and declare it as a service:

```
<?php

namespace You\ProjectBundle\Guzzle;

class MyGuzzleClient extends \Guzzle\Http\Client
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(null, array(
            'curl.options' => array('CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY' => 1)
        ));
    }
}
```

Then declare it as a service:

```
services:
    my_guzzle.client:
        class: You\ProjectBundle\Guzzle\MyGuzzleClient
```

Finally, use it as follow:

```
services:
    user.user_manager:
        class: Foo\UserBundle\Model\UserManager
        arguments:
            - @my_guzzle.client
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought there might be some other way. Probably using the expressions?